# Is there a way to update all documents by query in Elasticsearch 1.5?

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

We made some mistake to put one of the field with accent. So, the field contains `é` and we would like to update that to `e`.

We're using Elasticsearch 1.5. Is there a query we can run to update all the documents in one go or do I need to query all the documents and update them all using Elasticsearch lib?

We're using node.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running ES 1.5, you can install the [update-by-query](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery) plugin like this:

```
bin/plugin -install com.yakaz.elasticsearch.plugins/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery/2.5.1
```

When done, you can restart your ES server, and run the following query:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/your_index/_update_by_query' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    },
    "script" : "ctx._source.field = 'foo'"
}'
```